# Computing/approximating $\frac{d}{dt} ||e^{tA}||_F^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to compute or approximate
$$\frac{d}{dt}||e^{tA}||_F^2$$
where $||\cdot||_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm. $A$ is square, but it is not necessarily symmetric or diagonalizable. However, $A$ is always negative semidefinite.

I will accept an answer that shows how to either write down $\frac{d}{dt}||e^{tA}||_F^2$ in a useful form or gives a good approximation.

Comment: What is $F$ ???

Comment: Frobenius norm. I'll edit the question.

Comment: $F$ is a Hilbert space with the Frobenius norm, so $\frac{d}{{dt}}{\left\| {{e^{tA}}x} \right\|^2} = 2(A{e^{tA}}x,{e^{tA}}x){\text{ }}{\text{,}}\forall x \in F$.